# Use MAMP to open website on another pc - only see db content

Tags: php, database-connection, mamp

I’m trying to make access to my MAMP `localhost` from my mobile phone and other Windows PC. I’m currently using a Mac.

While I can see the database content but the website doesn’t render as usual (no images, stylesheet, etc…).

Therefore I assume the other PC can access the database but can’t use the files. Maybe the PHP files are not processed?

Does anyone have a suggestion on what could be the cause and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However I can see the database content but the website doesn't render
>   as usual (no images, stylesheet, etc)

Does your site on the MAMP install use hardcoded URLs for CSS, images & JavaScript?  Something like this:

```
http://localhost/images/a_great_image.png
```

If so, when a remote host accesses your site, they will not be able to see the content on URLs like that since they will be pointing to `localhost` and `localhost` is an address directly connected to the local machine. Meaning that any machine will only see `localhost` as their actual machine; never a remote machine. It’s a loopback hostname for testing & restricted local access.

The two solutions you have is to do the following:

- Change the `localhost` address to be the IP address of your computer on the network.  So if your computer is reached via the IP `10.0.1.3`, then the URL would be: `http://10.0.1.3/images/a_great_image.png`.
- Change the URLs to be relative URLs such as `/images/a_great_image.png` and maybe use `base` tag like this `<base href="http://10.0.1.3/" target="_blank">` on each page. That way all your links in URLs are relative, but the `base` is set once & is always `http://10.0.1.3/`.

Comment: Hi Jake, thanks for your quick reply! I've been looking for a solution for a big part of the day...  I mostly used relative links, but adding the base href with the IP address to my site did the trick!